# How to Convert Panda Strings Containing " $ - , " Characters to Float

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a `df` where some object columns contain `$`, `,`, negative numbers and `.`:

```
      Date Person      Salary      Change
0  11/1/15   Mike    $100.52        ($20)
1  11/1/15   Bill    $300.11    ($300.22)
2  11/1/15   Jake           -    ($1,100)
3  11/1/15   Jack    $411.43        $500 
4  11/1/15   Faye         NaN  $1,000.12 
5  11/1/15   Clay    $122.00        $100 
6  11/1/15   Dick  $1,663.33            -
```

I want to convert them to `float`, but when I try:

```
df['Salary'] = df['Salary'].str.replace(',', '').str.replace('$', '').str.replace('-', '').astype(float)
```

I get an empty `ValueError: could not convert string to float:`. It seems like it's the `-` is causing some issues, so is there an elegant way of handling it?

Comment: What’s the value of `’-‘` as a float?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a plain Python function because it is easier to write and test:

```
def conv(txt):
    txt = str(txt)
    txt = txt.strip()
    neg = txt.endswith(')')
    try:
        val = float(txt.strip('$()-,').replace(',', ''))
    except:
        val = np.nan
    return -val if neg else val

df['Salary'] = df['Salary'].apply(conv)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
df['Salary'] = df['Salary'].str.replace(',', '').str.replace('$', '').str.replace('-', '0').astype(float)
```

Your issue is most likely trying to convert blank strings to float. Python does not treat '' as a float. You are better off replacing it with 0.

Or a better solution:

```
df['Salary'] = df['Salary'].str.replace(',', '').str.replace('$', '').str.replace('-', '0')
df['Salary'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Salary'], errors = 'coerce', downcast = 'float')
```

If you want to see which rows are causing the issue since pd.to_numeric will coerce will return Nan.